# How to get know previous route name in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabnavigator

Lets suppose I am on Home screen. From Home screen I can go to ViewAllProduct page or ProductDetail page.
If I go to ViewAllProduct screen from Home, click on particular product, then goto ProductDetail page OR
If I go to ProductDetail screen from Home, click on view all product, then goto ViewAllProduct page.
Now what happening the screen are get stack on each other. What I want, if I'm on screen ViewAllProduct came from ProductDetail page, click on particular product in ViewAllProduct, the previous ProductDetail screen should show with different data instead pushing new ProductDetail screen or viceversa.

Comment: Maybe look into using `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement` rather than `push`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data). I think if you return the name of the product or something similar from the ViewAllProduct page when you call `Navigator.pop(context)`, you can use the return value in your ProductDetail screen to show something different.

Also, Please take some time to format your question... A big paragraph really isnt as easy to grasp as a well formatted list or pictures of the concept.